# RegisterActivity not loading after LoginActivity. It gives fatal runtime error

Tags: android

[Code in Pastebin here](http://paste.ofcode.org/3biiDniQJfQTAR3bzxGP58H)

I have `LoginActivity` class displaying A login screen and `RegisterActivity` which asks user to submit a form. But on clicking register here the `LoginRegister` Activity is not loading and app crashes.

Error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "" at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138) at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358) at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334) at com.example.mybucky.myapplication.LoginRegister.onCreate(Log‌​inRegister.java:32)
```

Comment: Print the stacktrace here

Comment: post you logcat error

Comment: post logcate here

Comment: and please add the code from line no 105 to 108 inside register button click. I think line no 108 is the problem .it will throw parsing exception as its parsing null

Comment: logs please....

Comment: its giving error at line no. 30 of LoginRegister

Comment: String uname=etUsername.getText().toString(); --Nullpointer exception

Comment: i am working on intellij idea so cant able to get logcat due to some unknown reason.

Comment: Voting to close question

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
                      at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
                      at com.example.mybucky.myapplication.LoginRegister.onCreate(LoginRegister.java:32)

Comment: We are advise not to put code in other link since it may be deleted someday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to write your code inside register button click otherwise it will throws numberformatexception on line no 108.

do like this:

```
final Button bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);

    bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String nme=etName.getText().toString();
            String uname=etUsername.getText().toString();
            String pasword=etPassword.getText().toString();
            int age1= Integer.parseInt( etAge.getText().toString() );

    LoginRegisterBean log = new LoginRegisterBean();
    log.setName(nme);
    log.setUsername(uname);
    log.setPassword(pasword);
    log.setAge(age1);

    helper.insertDetails(log);
        }
    });
```

> int age1= Integer.parseInt( etAge.getText().toString() )

here its parsing a null object to integer in your current code.

**EDIT**

Change your Sqlite Create query to :

```
String CREATE_REGISTER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_REGISTER + " ("
                + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL_NAME + " TEXT, "
                + COL_USERNAME + " TEXT, " +COL_PASSWORD+ " TEXT, " +COL_AGE+ " INTEGER);";
```

Insert method should be :

```
public void insertDetails(LoginRegisterBean l){
    db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(COL_NAME, l.getName()); // Contact Name
    values.put(COL_USERNAME, l.getUsername());
    values.put(COL_PASSWORD, l.getPassword());
    values.put(COL_AGE, l.getAge());

    db.insert(TABLE_REGISTER,null,values);
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: yes i got it.I made this error.Now it seems working but again getting sqlite exception on query

Comment: its giving me errors about value insertion.Error on insertion of values

Comment: Register table has no column named password

Comment: haha..you have too much mistakes in your code friend..follow the edited code

Comment: i know.i am a beginner here so it is bound to happen.Its giving same error after trying your edited code

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are referencing an id correctly, change `final EditText` `etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(username);`to `final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);` in your initialization of your username `EditText`

I would highly recommenced taking a read of this: [Android UI Fundamentals](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=z5jAHfSeeJMC&pg=PA205&lpg=PA205&dq=initializing%20widgets%20properly%20android&source=bl&ots=XF4qq5qby9&sig=tilwaP8nBg7ftxaAX9cbkYLroYo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwisir2koYXRAhWGK8AKHQymAKQQ6AEINDAE#v=onepage&q=initializing%20widgets%20properly%20android&f=false).

Edit:

For your age `EditText` add one line to the `XML` like so:

```
<EditText
  .... 
 android:id="@+id/age"
 android:inputType="number"
/>
```

to ensure its always a number.

Comment: its causing same problem

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
                      at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
                      at com.example.mybucky.myapplication.LoginRegister.onCreate(LoginRegister.java:32)

Comment: no i have converted the edit  to String and then from string to integer.I got the problem now.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please change  `final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(username);` to

```
final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
```

and

Just put a condition

```
   int age1;

            if (etAge.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                 age1=0; 
        } else{
                 age1= Integer.parseInt( etAge.getText().toString() ); 
                }
```

Comment: i am getting this is stacktrace     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
                      at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
                      at com.example.mybucky.myapplication.LoginRegister.onCreate(LoginRegister.java:32)

Comment: Just put a condition 

if etAge.getText().toString().equals(""){
age1=0;
}
else{

int age1= Integer.parseInt( etAge.getText().toString() );
}

Comment: oh i used plaintext under Age so thats why the problem is occuring.It accepts only integer

Comment: Is this fine ??

Comment: no.Its nt getting printed.Its showing numberformatexception at line number 32

Comment: Is your line 32  int age1= Integer.parseInt( etAge.getText().toString() ); ?

Comment: Use  android:inputType="number" in the xml layout for your age EditText and try without leaving it blank

Comment: ya i did that.i am getting sqlite exception on insertion of values.Column password not found in table register